# Infinite wait for reply from server using sockets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, sockets

I'm trying to send a message to the API of a server in order to get a reply. I am using the following code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('h68.p.ctrader.com',5211)
sock.connect(server_address)

message = "8=FIX.4.4|9=87|35=0|49=theBroker.12345|56=cServer|57=QUOTE|50=BVN's Message|34=1|52=20180322-21:26:01|10=101"

sock.send(bytes(message,'utf-8'))
data = sock.recv(3)
print(data)
sock.close()
```

However, when executing it, the message is sent to the server, but at the moment of receiving the reply from the server [data = sock.recv (3)], the program does not go on. It keeps the cursor blinking, like in an infinite loop. What is the cause of this problem? Was it the script? The message sent to the server? The server itself? How to solve the problem?

Note: This message is in a format required by the server API, which consists of "tag" = "value" | "tag" = "value" | "tag" = "value" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation for this API you're using turns up a couple of problems:

- You're missing a `|` at the very end of the message.
- You shouldn't actually be sending `|`s at all, that's just a human-readable translation of the actual message.  All of them need to be replaced with `\x01` or `\u0001` (depending on whether you're creating a byte string or a Unicode string), the actual tag separator character.